# Apply color to a specific word in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to find a word in a string, which starts wit `BK` or `WL`, followed by 2 numbers. If the numbers are smaller or equal than 50 I want to change the whole word's color to blue, otherwise to red.

For e.g. if I have:

`32FML EKKF BK30`

I need to return:

`32FML EKKF <span class="blue">BK30</span>`

Comment: `"32FML EKKF BK30".replace(/(BK30)/, '<span class=""blue">$1</span>')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `/((BK|WL)(\d{2}))/g` regex pattern .

If you validate less then `50`, apply some [`ternary operator`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfrMum6JzUAhUDQY8KHaLVDsAQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator&usg=AFQjCNEyfU4zvkUJSNIonRwYQ86E1fetTg&sig2=K2pq-y3GSJPun8-M5qQKxw) in replace function .parse the string to number use with [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjaz8jH6JzUAhXMuY8KHYrvA2MQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g&sig2=uK0VkTx4evVtcOuV99cxKw)

**[Demo regex and pattern explanation](https://regex101.com/r/k8aBGJ/2/)**

```js
var str ='32FML EKKF BK30 BK66'
document.body.innerHTML=str.replace(/((BK|WL)(\d{2}))/g ,(a,b,c,d) => parseFloat(d)<50 ? '<span class="red">'+b+'</span>' : b)
```

```css
.red{
color:red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that my comment is the right answer so... You can use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that and it's useful possibility of passing matched parts of string to replacement pattern. Something like this:

```
var str = "32FML EKKF BK30";

var highlighted = str.replace(/(BK30)/, '<span class=""blue">$1</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

What MysterX said is true and I have your regular expression as well:

```
"32FML EKKF BK30".replace(/((BK|WL)+\d{2})/, '<span class=""blue">$1</span>')
```